# Lambda expressions in android

Tags: android, intellij-idea, lambda

How use lambda expressions in android?
For example, I compile this code in IntelliJ IDEA:

```
package com.example.myapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        test s = () -> {return "Lambda expressions test";};
        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle("Lambda expression")
                .setMessage(s.t())
                .create();
        alertDialog.show();
    }
}
interface test {
    public String t();
}
```

But have this erorrs:

```
Information:Using javac 1.8.0_05 to compile java sources
Information:36 errors
Information:0 warnings
Information:Compilation completed with 36 errors and 0 warnings in 29 sec
Error:Android Dex: [myappі] UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
Error:Android Dex: [myappі] com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: InvokeDynamic not supported
```

How to set up so you can use lambda expressions?

Comment: android supports java 6/7 not 8 i guess. lambda is introduced in java 8 i guess

Comment: yes, lambda is introduced in java 8, but what can I do if there is already a lot of code is written with a lambda expression

Comment: @Raghunandan You are wrong.  Lambdas work easily in Android Studio if you set your build.gradle to use Java 8.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23318109/is-it-possible-to-use-java-8-for-android-development

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky hmm that too using retrolamda.

Comment: @Raghunandan what's the difference?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky i am not sure i haven't tried it. i din't know about retrolambda when i commented. I found nothing in the docs

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Android only supports java 6 and 7. You can use plugins to get lambdas though such as https://github.com/evant/gradle-retrolambda.

Comment: It's supporting java 8 now!

Answer (score 3):

In your **build.gradle** add this:

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

Assuming you installed Java 8 on your machine!

Also, add this:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
    classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:2.5.0'
}
```

And finally:

```
apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'
```

Answer (score 1):

Java 8 language features are now supported by the Android build system

> Yesterday, we released Android Studio 2.4 Preview 6. Java 8 language
>   features are now supported by the Android build system in the javac/dx
>   compilation path. Android Studio's Gradle plugin now desugars Java 8
>   class files to Java 7-compatible class files, so you can use lambdas,
>   method references and other features of Java 8.

**Source** : https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/04/java-8-language-features-support-update.html

**Edit:** 06/01/2017

Lambda Expressions now supported in Android Studio 3.0