# Best way to double sort in java using Collections.sort

Tags: java, android, sorting

In java I have a custom class, and I sort it like this:

```
public static void sortList(List<FishCategory> categories) {
    Collections.sort(categories, new Comparator<FishCategory>(){
        public int compare(FishCategory s1, FishCategory s2) {
            return s1.getName().compareTo(s2.getName());
        }
    });
}
```

But like sql where you can do this:

```sql
select * from mytable
order by id, name
```

I want to double sort in java. I want to sort by this (Note: im using `getParentId`) as the first sort, then I want to sort like above.

```
public static void sortList(List<FishCategory> categories) {
    Collections.sort(categories, new Comparator<FishCategory>(){
        public int compare(FishCategory s1, FishCategory s2) {
            return s1.getParentId().compareTo(s2.getParentId());
        }
    });
}
```

I can't just run both functions one right after the next cause that would cancel out the first sorting. I need to sort the way sql does it (i.e. sort the sorted groups).

So I want to sort by `.getParentId()` first, then `.getName()`.

Does anyone know a good way to do this easily?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple modification for the `Comparator`:

```
final int diff = s1.getParentId() - s2.getParentId();
return diff != 0 ? diff : s1.getName().compareTo(s2.getName());
```

If `getParentId()` has a difference, sort it by the manner. Else sort by `getName()`.

> As pointed out [by this comment by Pshemo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24644124/best-way-to-double-sort-in-java-using-collections-sort/24644148#comment38199326_24644148), you can use the following in place for `diff` initialization:

```
= Integer.compare(s1.getParentId(), s2.getParentId());
```

Comment: getParentId returns an integer, compare to wont take ints.

Comment: @omega It auto-boxes to become an `Integer`. `java.lang.Integer` has `compareto()` specified.

Comment: I tried it. Eclipses complains and says compare to wont work for primitive  type int.

Comment: ok I changed the return type of getParentId to Integer, and then ur previous answer worked.

Comment: @omega Ah but if it's using the primitive `int`, please keep it that way. Using `Integer` will force the interpreter to box an `int` whenever `getParentId()` is called. Most of the times using the operator `-` is preferable over `compareTo()`.

Comment: ok Im using your current answer and went back to primitive int.

Comment: Don't use `s1.getParentId() - s2.getParentId()` unless you are entirely sure that you are subtracting only positive values. To be safe it is better to use `Integer.compare(x, y)` like in this case `diff = Integer.compare(s1.getParentId(),s2.getParentId());`

Comment: @Pshemo Actually the use of "Id" in the method implied that they are unique positive values. But thanks for the point - I'll add to my answer!

Comment: I can't use Integer.compare because it needs android api 19, but my minimum is 16. The getParentId only returns values >= 0, so I think the other way should be ok.

Answer (score 5):

Write a single Comparator that tests both fields, consulting the second only if the first is equal. Plug that into the sort. Done.

Note that you can also write a Comparator that wraps around two Comparators (or a list of Comparators), if you want a more general solution for multi-level sorts.

Answer (score 3):

Since Java 8 Comparator has `thenComparing` default method in which you can add next comparator which should be used if "original" comparator would decide that values are equal.

So your code can look like

```
public static void sortList(List<FishCategory> categories) {
    Collections.sort(categories, new Comparator<FishCategory>(){
        public int compare(FishCategory s1, FishCategory s2) {
            return s1.getParentId().compareTo(s2.getParentId());
        }
    }.thenComparing(new Comparator<FishCategory>(){
        public int compare(FishCategory s1, FishCategory s2) {
            return s1.getName().compareTo(s2.getName());
        }
    }));

    Comparator.comparing(FishCategory::getParentId);
}
```

or you can simplify it more with `Comparator.comparing` method which accept `Function` which returns `Comparable` field, so in your case you could even use lambdas and write something like

```
public static void sortList(List<FishCategory> categories) {
    Collections.sort(categories, Comparator
            .comparing(FishCategory::getParentId)
            .thenComparing(Comparator.comparing(FishCategory::getName)));
}
```

Comment: Fancy Java 8 `Comparator` builders! Are there similar alternatives for Java 7?

Comment: I'm actually using this for android, and according to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23318109/is-it-possible-to-use-java-8-for-android-development it says java 8 is not supported, but still this looks like a good answer.

Answer (score 2):

First check it using the parentId, if it is equal then compare for the name

See the code below:

```
public static void sortList(List<FishCategory> categories) {
    Collections.sort(categories, new Comparator<FishCategory>(){
        public int compare(FishCategory s1, FishCategory s2) {
            int diff = s1.getParentId() - s2.getParentId();
            if (diff != 0)
                return diff;
            return s1.getName().compareTo(s2.getName());
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: `s1.getParentId() - s2.getParentId()` is a bad idea due to integer overflow