# No Java 1.8 compiler compliance level when running Android Bundle/Eclipse Juno under Oracle JDK 8

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am using Android Bundle/Eclipse Juno under Oracle JDK 8 as the default Java on my Fedora 21 KDE box. There is no Java compiler compliance level 1.8 in settings. When I opened the Eclipse compiler compliance level was set to 1.4 and it goes up to 1.8. Is there something wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eclipse juno doesn't magically gain Java 1.8 compiler support because you install Java 8. Juno was released in [June 2012](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Juno/Simultaneous_Release_Plan) while Java 8 was released [March 2014](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8_.28March_18.2C_2014.29). The first version of eclipse with Java 8 support was [Kepler](https://wiki.eclipse.org/JDT/Eclipse_Java_8_Support_For_Kepler) (through an after-release JDT update); Luna supports Java 8 out of the box.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what Elliot wrote in [his Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27310252/139985), you won't be able to run Java 8 code on Android.  Android platforms only support linguistic features up to Java 7, and even then the support is not complete.

Reference:

- [Is it possible to use Java 8 for Android development?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23318109/is-it-possible-to-use-java-8-for-android-development)

Comment: Thanks I am not looking into using Java 8 for Android. Eclipse provided through official or distro channels often tend to include a lot of things that as a beginner I may not need. It is not a big issue but nonetheless using official tool chain is preferred. And that is why i am using archaic version of Eclipse. Fedora 21 dropped the support for Java 7 because it would EOL before Fedora 21 goes EOL. So I end up with a Java 8 and Eclipse Juno install.

Comment: I'm not convinced by your reasoning.  A lot of the "things that a developer doesn't need" are actually pretty much essential ... and stuff that a beginner **ought to be learning**; e.g. version control, build tools.  But be that as it may, if you want to stick with an archaic version of Eclipse, you won't be able to develop Java 8 code using the IDE.

Comment: I hope you do understand that learning takes time and you tackle one problem at a time. My knowledge of Java expands to one online class and one book. I have learned basics of version control, build tools, etc. by picking up articles here and there. I need to get my basics of Java solid before I go on learning tools and things that revolves around programming.