# Lambda expressions not supported -source 1.7 (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android

I was trying to run my android project in Android Studio, but I can't do so.

I am getting this error:

```
Error:(23, 47) error: lambda expressions are not supported in -source 1.7
(use -source 8 or higher to enable lambda expressions)
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJava'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

**I am using JDK 1.8.**

Any idea why is this happening? Any resoultion.

*PS: There are couple of similar questions in Stack but none resolved this problem. Please understand the problem before you tag Duplicate.*

Comment: Closing as a duplicate, especially because of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23318644/675383): _"Android does not support Java 8. It only supports up to Java 7 (if you have kitkat) and still it doesn't have invokedynamic, only the new syntax sugar."_

Answer (score 5):

Here is the solution:

Android cannot be build on **JDK 1.8**;
And Lambda expression cannot be used in JDK below 1.8.

The solution is to go back to JDK 1.7 and avoid using Lambda sign.
In place of using:

```
button.setOnClickListener((v) -> {


                    Intent newIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
                    MainActivity.this.startActivity(newIntent);
                }
            });
```

We have to use this:

```
       button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                Intent newIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
                MainActivity.this.startActivity(newIntent);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score -2):

Looks like you need to pass : `-source 8` to the compiler as an argument.

Comment: how can i set the compiler argument?

Comment: Have a read of this...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23318109/is-it-possible-to-use-java-8-for-android-development

Comment: my preference is different from that in Windows, shown in the link. didn't helped much. I am using Mac.