# In Android Studio how can I configure my project to use Java 8

Tags: android-studio, java-8

I recently started development with Android Studio 1.1.0 (bundle 135.1740770 for Windows) having JDK version "1.8.0_40" installed (64 Bit).

So far everything works fine, except I **cannot import** classes added with Java 8. I recognized it when trying to import **java.util.Optional**, but it's the same with e.g. java.util.stream.

May it be the case that my project somehow only uses a Java 7 subset of my JDK's standard library? And is it possible (recommended) to change that? I looked for a java version param in properties files, manifest and IDE settings. Didn't find anything like that.. anyone experienced something like that?

Btw. following the first comment in [Is it possible to use Java 8 for Android development?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23318109) it should be possible basically, but it seems to only cover Eclipse..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you read further down in your linked comments, you will find the solution:

> You may use JDK 6 or above for Android development. However, the compilation supports Java version 6 (and 7 in case of KitKat).

So yes, you may use JDK 8 for development, but you need to set the language level to JDK 6 or JDK 7. You cannot use any features that were added to JDK 8. To set the language level in Android Studio, go to:

`File > Project Structure > Project > Select Project language level`

Comment: oh how bad, Java 8 stuff looked quite promising language-wise. you're totally right. searching for that shows it seems to be not even in reach.. http://www.quora.com/When-will-Android-support-Java-8