# Can't install Android Studio on Windows 10 - JDK not found

Tags: android-studio, java-8, windows-10, environment

Found out that this is [bugging](https://teamtreehouse.com/community/i-cant-install-the-jdk-7-64-for-windows-i-download-the-android-studio-but-it-will-not-run-without-it) a [lot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29070668/android-studio-not-installing-even-if-jdk-8-is-installed) [of](http://dcastro9.blogspot.com.br/2013/05/running-android-studio-on-windows-78.html) [people](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23318109/is-it-possible-to-use-java-8-for-android-development) from various Java versions. I read all those links but none of them helped me.
My setup:

- Windows 10
- JDK 8 installed in C:\Java8
- Set JAVA_HOME to "C:\Java8"
- Set JDK_HOME to "C:\Java8"
- %JAVA_HOME%\bin added to %PATH%
- Android Studio Bundle version android-studio-bundle-141.2456560-windows

Trying to install, step by step:

[image: Initial image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Am I missing anything in this?

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: how about add `\bin` to `JAVA_HOME`? I don't use %JAVA_HOME% at PATH, but instead hard code path of jdk: `c:\java8\bin`

Comment: can you tell me where is your java located?? And make sure you download 64 bit java

Comment: Java home is C:\Java8, it is 64-bit

Answer (score 0):

you need java 7 to use most of android versions. Android N introduces Java 8
http://developer.android.com/preview/j8-jack.html