# Dex Error in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I get this error while executing.

```
 com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

This is my Dependency

```
 dependencies {

    compile files('libs/FlurryAnalytics-5.0.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpcore-4.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpmime-4.3.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/ima-android-sdk-beta9.jar')
    compile files('libs/twitter4j-core-3.0.4.jar')
    compile files('libs/universal-image-loader-1.9.0-with-   sources.jar')
    compile files('libs/appsee.jar')

    compile project(':facebookLibrary')
    compile project(':vASTSampleLib')

    compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:7.0.0')
    compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:7.0.0')
}
```

I have Facebook Library and the dependency

```
dependencies {
   compile project(':facebookSDK')     
   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
}
```

And finally the Facebook SDK

```
 dependencies {
   compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
   compile files('libs/bolts-android-1.1.2.jar')
 }
```

So there is no duplicate.jar files used. Why do I get Dex Error.

Comment: Have you tried doing [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20989317/multiple-dex-files-define-landroid-support-v4-accessibilityservice-accessibility/21100040#21100040) ?

Comment: check this similar question asked  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29296650/android-with-gradle-java-finished-with-non-zero-exit-value-2