# Android : Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'

Tags: android

Am developing an app in Android Studio. While executing am getting an error

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.polus.binil.recyclerviewdemo"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
   }
   }

   dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+'
compile "com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.4.0"
}
```

can any one please help to solve this issue

Comment: similar question try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29296650/android-with-gradle-java-finished-with-non-zero-exit-value-2

Comment: Try to run `./gradlew assembleDebug --debug` to get the full stacktrace.

Comment: Also it may be caused by the duplicated dependency of the recyclerview.

Comment: HI Kuba Spaty, I rebuild the app by removing the duplicate dependency , but same error again.  As you told " ./gradlew assembleDebug --debug" , how to do that

Comment: Hi Raghavendra, it not solve the problem by updating to the JDK 8 , That's why put this question @Raghavendra

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+'` from `dependencies` you have same multiple `dependencies` added:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.1.1'
    compile "com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.4.0"
    }
```

Then rebuild project.

Answer (score 0):

Its jar file issue . Picasso as jar file  , I import it as jar as a module . So no need " compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs') " in dependencies

**Wrong code**

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.1.1'
compile "com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.4.0"
}
```

**Correct code**

```
  dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.1.1'
compile "com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.4.0"
}
```