# How can i resolve? Execution failed for task ‘:app:dexDebug’

Tags: java, android, android-studio

**Error Log:**

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'. > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29296650/android-with-gradle-java-finished-with-non-zero-exit-value-2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have  libraries and methods, then you can enable multi dex support by declaring it in the gradle config.

```
defaultConfig {        
    // Enabling multidex support.
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```