# android studio : lambda expressions are not supported in -source 1.7 (use -source 8 or higher to enable lambda expressions)

Tags: java, android, lambda

Happy to know that java introduced [Lambda expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) in java version 8.

I was working in android studio. And I noticed that `DialogInterface.OnClickListener()` was showing underline and became grey colored as below:

[image]

So, I did `alter + enter` on that line and found option to replace the code with Lambda Expressions, as below:

[image]

Which resulted in something below:

[image]

After running the code it showed me this error:

> Error:(160, 69) error: lambda expressions are not supported in -source
>   1.7 (use -source 8 or higher to enable lambda expressions)

But I am already using java `jdk1.8.0_31`. Is there anything else, I need to install ?

Can anyone help me out please..

Comment: Have you read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23318109/is-it-possible-to-use-java-8-for-android-development

Comment: Java 8 is not supported but you can use retrolanbda for the same effect https://github.com/evant/gradle-retrolambda

Answer (score 11):

You cannot compile Java 8 sources for Android, because Android SDK does not support Java 8 yet.

But there is one way to use Lambdas in your code - [RetroLambda](https://github.com/evant/gradle-retrolambda). This is a little hack that allows you to use some of the features of Java 8 in your project.

Comment: Have u used it..did you got any side-effect about this lib !

Comment: @Shubh i tried to use it in production few months ago, but unfortunately i faced a lot of problems with it. Bamboo CI did not supported Java 8 means you cannot compile your project there. Also for some versions of gradle plugin project did not compiles, and espresso tests did not worked with retrolambdas. Probably this problems already solved but i did not checked

Comment: So this is not recommended to use it for now at least, Right!

Answer (score 6):

I don't think `Android` development is ready yet for `Java 8`. `Android Studio` supports the compile level `Java 7` whether you installed `Java 7` or `Java 8`. So, if you want to use new features of `Java 8`, I think you have to wait `Android Studio` to support `compile level Java 8`.

Comment: yes might be...you are right here!.

Comment: Instant run not being supported is the main drawback and what caused me to revert back to Java 7 honestly, PLUS all the really cool language features in Java 8 (Streams for example) are only supported with API 24 and above..which is insane