# Gradle Android Project with Java 8 module

Tags: java, android, gradle, java-8, android-gradle-plugin

As I've seen in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23318109/is-it-possible-to-use-java-8-for-android-development), `Java 8` is not officially supported by `Android` right now. So I'm interested if it is possible to build `Android` module with `Java 7` and `Java` module (as a dependency) with `Java 8`.

As an example, I'm trying to create a `Gradle` project that will contain one `Android` module and one `Java` module as a dependency.
With the following `compileOptions` set for both modules, everything works fine.

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}
```

But if I try to change `compileOptions` for my `Java` module to

```
compileJava {
    sourceCompatibility = 1.8
    targetCompatibility = 1.8
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':fc-android:preDexFreeDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

So the question, is that actually possible to have `Android` module compiled with `1.7` version and  dependent `Java` module compiled with `1.8`? And if not, so why?

**UPDATE:**

[Retrolamba](https://github.com/evant/gradle-retrolambda) for `Gradle` (mentioned by @Saeed) is good, however they have only support of lambdas, so not access to `Stream API`, `DateTime API` and other features. Imagine if we have `*.jar` file built with `Java 8` (no `Android` code). I think that we can't use such `*.jar` file as a dependency for `Android` module, because it's bytecode will not be supported by `ART` or `Dalvik`, but only by `JVM` for `Java 8`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Android can support java 1.7 since API 19 (as you see in this [doc](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Using-sourceCompatibility-1.7) there is no mention of java 1.8) and also it doesn't use JVM and using ART or Dalvik instead ,So it generates [Dalvik bytecode](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/index.html#art-technical-information).

I think if we want to use java 1.8  as `compileOptions` maybe android run time can't understand some new features in java 8 like lambda so gradle doesn't allow you to compile your code and you got that exception.

So you need a bytecode transformer to use

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
  }
```

Read this [tutorial](http://www.aphex.cx/2014/07/java-8-on-android-with-little-hacking.html) .It converts your bytecodes to be compatible with java 7.I've tested this before and it works for me.

**Update 2016**

Android N [introduces support for Java 8 language features](http://developer.android.com/preview/j8-jack.html).

Comment: Retrolamba is good, however they have only support of lambdas, so not access to `Stream API`, `DateTime API` and other features. Imagine if we have `*.jar` file built with `Java 8` (no `Android` code). I think that we can't use such `*.jar` file as a dependency for `Android` module, because it's bytecode will not be supported by `ART` or `Dalvik`, but only by `JVM` for `Java 8`. Am I right, @Saeed?

Comment: yes it's true, actually they would need to be rebuilt.