# JdK1.8.0_45 path issue Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, java-8

I am getting this issue repeatedly "**Installing Android Studio, does not point to a valid JVM installation error**" while launching Android Studio.

I have installed Eclipse and Android studio Both on My System. Eclipse is working fine but Android Studio is not Working now. Means Before Installation of Eclipse it was working well.

I have Set the Path="C:\Program Files(x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin".
And I have also installed jdk1.7.0 and jdk1.6.0_07 on my system.

![enter image description here][1]

Comment: Android platform does not support Java 8. Choose Java 6 or 7.

Comment: But Eclipse is working fine with android platform with JAVA 8.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to use Java 8 for Android development?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23318109/is-it-possible-to-use-java-8-for-android-development)

Comment: Yes, but not with relation to the compilation unit - see the duplicate link and discussions there. Anyway, you can change the sdk path in Android Studio appropriately.

Comment: yes its working i have set jre8 in eclipse.

Comment: but compilation is at 1.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android Studio Works With JDK 7 ans JDK 8 both:

Need to set jdk path like this;

JAVA_HOME = "C:\Program Files(x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_45"

Comment: however it does not use the java 8 features