# Is it a good practice to use JAVA 8 for android development?

Tags: android, retrolambda

I read the instructions for using Java8 for android development from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23318644/4412460) answer and ([orfjackal/retrolambda](https://github.com/orfjackal/retrolambda)).

I wanted to know if it is a **good practice** to use this technique to implement Java 8. Does this affects the **application performance**?

It is mentioned in the [blog](http://zserge.com/blog/android-lambda.html)-
*retrolambda* *It does this by transforming your Java 8 compiled bytecode so that it can run on an older Java runtime.*

Comment: Unless this is some contract for a huge project, it doesn't really matter. Just use whatever java you want.

Comment: Thanks for the help @Takendarkk. I think what you are saying is true. I will use it and see if it is stable enough for my application. Might not make huge difference but i hope it will certainly not reduce the application performance (*if i use properly*).

Comment: @Harsh I used `retrolambda` it is working fine in android. Use java 8 stream library if you using some Java 8 APIs.

Comment: I've had the same question when I came to an existing Android project production that used Java 8. Now, 9 months later and no problems, I feel a lot better about using Java 8 in Android.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is too early to say that use Java 8 is a good practice for android development, officially android needs the Java 6 JDK as mentioned at the bottom of this page: https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html

Also, there are some Android APIs that even not support try with resources, so I don't think they'll support Java 8 at all.

Comment: I read the link. But I can use java 8 through [orfjackal/retrolambda](https://github.com/orfjackal/retrolambda) I know officially android doesn't support it but what if we use Java 8 through the above method will it affect the performance? Or will it not create any significant difference or little difference?

Comment: It will be inestable, if you decide to use Java 8 be prepaired for some weird magic errors

Comment: Okay. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Hope I've been helpful! :)

Comment: I will use it and see how the result comes.

Comment: Share the experience if you can ;)

Comment: @Harsh : How it gone? Was this the solution for you?

Comment: So far so good. I can't judge whether it affected the performance in a good way but i haven't faced any issues. I love using lambda expressions. I have been using RxJava in some projects and I have to write lesser code. Specially with the inner classes gone, code looks much cleaner now.