# Use lambda expression to create an AlertDialog

Tags: android, lambda, java-8, android-alertdialog, retrolambda

I have my Android studio set with these:

```
    classpath "me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.2.2"
    classpath 'me.tatarka.retrolambda.projectlombok:lombok.ast:0.2.3.a2'
```

And I am trying to use lambdas to know what I can do or not.

When I did the following code:

```
    alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Okay", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });
```

The IDE grayed out the `new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()` telling me it could be replaced with a lambda. Nothing more or less. After looking into [**several**](http://marksunghunpark.blogspot.com.br/2015/05/lets-start-lambda-in-android.html) [*examples*](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/2iokwh/retrolambda_java_8_lambda_syntax_when_an/). I tried things like:

```
    alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Okay", (DialogInterface dialog) -> {
            dialog.cancel();
    });
```

Also these:

```
alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton((DialogInterface) d -> d.cancel());
```

Among the errors:

> Error:(99, 64) error: incompatible types: DialogInterface is not a functional interface
>   multiple non-overriding abstract methods found in interface DialogInterface

How should I use lambda in this case?

Comment: This question may be interesting for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23318109/is-it-possible-to-use-java-8-for-android-development

Answer (score 11):

`onClick` takes two parameters, and your example tries only show one.  Be sure to include the `which` parameter in your lambda.

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setPositiveButton("Okay", 
                                  (dialog, which) -> dialog.cancel());
```