# Does Android Studio works with Java 8?

Tags: android, android-studio, java-8

I'm going to install `Java 8` on my computer but before doing that I want to know if `Android Studio` works with it. I look here on `Stackoverflow` and found this: [Is it possible to use Java 8 for Android development?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23318109/is-it-possible-to-use-java-8-for-android-development).

I saw the answer of `ekcr1` where he says:

> Android does not support Java 8. It only supports up to Java 7 (if you have kitkat) and still it doesn't have invokedynamic, only the new syntax sugar.

but his answer it's from Apr 27 '14. What about right now?

If I look at the page of [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html?pkg=studio) I can see that `JDK 7` is required if you develop for `Android 5.0` or higher but it doesn't say nothing about `Java 8`.

Is it possible to use `Android Studio` with `Java 8` or still doesn't work?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: i use it with Java 8 and it works prefectly fine. Just try it out. If you do not want to break anything, use a Virtual Machine :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can be wrong, but I'm almost certain you can install Java 8 instead of 7 and not have any issues.

The quoted post is referring to features of Java 8. It doesn't matter that you have 8 installed, you're not getting any features that weren't available in Java 7, because that's what android uses.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it works. Please try it. It should be working.

Answer (score 0):

Some people have answered a different question. As I recall android studio runs fine under java 8. Android studio is merely an ide that runs on win or Linux. Android runs on tablets and phones. Android, the OS, does not support have 8. You can however use closures via a bytecode post compile step in gradle. The name eludes me at the moment.