# Using Java 8 in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, java-8

Im using android studio and I want to use lambda expression that are available only from java 8, and when I try to use it I get:

```
Lambda expression are not supported at this language level.
```

So, how can I change that on AndroidStudio?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/23318109/5420829. Install JDK 8 and set the compiler in the AndroidStudio to JDK 8.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> So, how can I change that on AndroidStudio?

you can't. Android supports up to java 7. If you want to use AS only for Lambda, you can use [gradle-retrolamba](https://github.com/evant/gradle-retrolambda) or [retrolambda](https://github.com/orfjackal/retrolambda), which back-port retrolambda on java 6/7

Answer (score 2):

Android supports Java 6 up to KitKat (4.4) with some minor syntactic sugar (like diamond operator), and Java 7 from there on (Lollipop and Marshmallow atm). Lambdas and other Java 8 stuff are available only as plugins (e. g. [gradle-retrolambda](https://github.com/evant/gradle-retrolambda) or the original [retrolambda](https://github.com/orfjackal/retrolambda)). They will probably be included in API at some point in time (like Java 7 and KitKat), but it doesn't seem likely it'll be very soon.