# Does Android SDK with API 23 (Marshmallow) supports Java 8?

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, lambda

Does IntelliJ Android Studio last update (From 30/Jan/2016) supports Java 8?

I used a lambda expression

```
mButton.setOnClickListener((View v) -> {
    // do something here
});
```

then Android Studio tells me I have an error and when I resolve the problem (Alt+spacebar) I choose the Change to Java 8 (or something like that) and it works the lambda but the libraries from Android seems to be unsupported it marks all in red.

Any options for supporting Java 8 in Android Studio?

Note: I'm using the last API Level

Comment: Java 8 isn't supported right now.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23318109/is-it-possible-to-use-java-8-for-android-development and lots of others

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, Java 8 isn't supported. What you can do instead to write Lambdas and method references is to include [retrolambda](https://github.com/evant/gradle-retrolambda) dependency to your project. Same with streams, here is [a backport library](https://github.com/aNNiMON/Lightweight-Stream-API). Alternatively, consider using [kotlin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6954?pr=androidstudio).

Comment: @HoracioGarza Just wanted to add, that for Java 8 streams, there is also the [streamsupport library](https://sourceforge.net/projects/streamsupport/) which is much closer to Java 8 Stream syntax and functionality than the [Lightweight-Stream-API](https://github.com/aNNiMON/Lightweight-Stream-API). For example, it also supports parallel streams.

Answer (score 1):

Android is using the retired Apache Harmony as its Java implementation and I believe Harmony is on Java 6, so no, Java 8 is not supported.

Java 8 will be supported in Android N though as it will use OpenJDK instead of Harmony.