# will lambda expression used inside layout file for data binding purpose also work on all version of android?

Tags: android

I am trying to bind a method inside layout file something like `@{viewmodel.setPrintdata()}` but it is not working unless i use `@{()->viewmodel.setPrintdata()}` but i came to know that lambda expression is not working on all version of android. What i should do?

Answer (score 0):

Lambda expressions are not associated with any of the android version instead it is the feature of Java 8. If you are using Java 8 in your code it will work on all devices.

Hope you get the point.

Comment: @nauman you should see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35106196/does-android-sdk-with-api-23-marshmallow-supports-java-8

Comment: you are reviewing very old thread. See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23318109/is-it-possible-to-use-java-8-for-android-development

Comment: @nauman thanks.. but one more doubt if you can make clear to me .. can i use stream api also?

Comment: if you are using java8 then yes you can use java stream api.

Comment: @nauman this official link states that i can use Stream API when minsdkversion is 24. https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support.html#supported_features  could you confirm please.