# Android JSONException: No value for property

Tags: android, json, debugging, android-studio

I am facing an issue while trying to retrieve value from JSONObject.
I've spent an hour researching the solution, but non of suggestions work in other posts or anywhere else.

When I run above code on emulator, it throws error and I am able to catch it.

> JSONException: No value for property

However If I put a breakpoint in **try** block and run the app, with Android Studio's **Evaluate Expression** tool I am able to get non empty value with the same code, and it does not throw exception. So the initial JSONObject **userInfo** definitely contains the data I am trying to get, and it works if I run it in debug mode by hands.

Here is my code.

```
    String value = "";
    try {
        JSONObject obj = userInfo.getJSONObject("data");
        value = obj.getString(param);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Emulator is configured with standard Nexus 5 configs with android studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending some time researching, I found the problem.
It was because I previously modified **gradle** to be able to use [java 8 lambdas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33918771/2043297).

So reverting project JDK back to 7 worked for me.
I hope this will save somebody's time.