# How to encode string in Base 64 without apache library in android 23(marshmallow)?

Tags: java, android, apache

```
EncodingUtils.getBytes(payload, "BASE64");
```

this is the line which we were using with apache library included in gradle to get bytes of payload string with char set as BASE64

after removing this

```
useLibrary  'org.apache.http.legacy'
```

Encoding util class is not getting resolved so what is the best way to do this same function in Android ?

Input

```
device_type=1&firstname=hhj&=
```

This is the way the input would be a long string which has other parameters too output would be in bytes since i have to post this result in url like this

```
mWebView.postUrl(url, myRes);
```

Comment: Not quite without apache, but without that one, though with another lib: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13109588/base64-encoding-in-java

Comment: Also according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23318109/is-it-possible-to-use-java-8-for-android-development if you need only for android 5.0+ then you can use the 1 line Java 8 solution from the previous link

Comment: Isn't there a way without any library like android inbuilt class or something?

Comment: Since API level 8 there is http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html

Comment: So we are removing the apache library for all versions not only for marshmallow

Answer (score 1):

Android has a built-in [Base64](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html) class which can be used, starting from API level 8.

Comment: myRes=Base64.encodeToString(payload.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT).getBytes();

Comment: @PallavGrover Show input and output and expected output

Comment: check the edited questions this is the input output would be in bytes

Comment: @PallavGrover You didn't show how the output from the built-in class is wrong. Or why you need to Base64 that and get bytes out of it.

Comment: @PallavGrover Tested with your string, I got exactly the correct result from Base64 encoding with that class.