# Is It Possible to get Arraylist of product name from Arraylist of custom class without looping

Tags: java, android, arrays

Suppose I have class:

```
class Product {
   int pId;
   String pName;
   int pPrice;
}
```

I have `Arraylist<Product>`, so can I get `ArrayList<String>` which contain **product name only** without loop.

Say with help of cursor or collection utils or any other thing in android.

Comment: How you are adding data of product in arraylist? Because if you are adding product in arraylist at that same time you will have product name which you need to add in another arraylist, i think that is the best way to do that. And if you are dealing with DB then you can directly query and get data.

Comment: give us some more code where do you add Products to the list.

Answer (score 1):

In **Java 8** you can use `stream` and `map` function on the list of your products.

Assume you have:

```
List<Product> productList = new ArrayList<Product>();
productList.add(new Product(1, "test", 100));
productList.add(new Product(1, "test2", 100));
```

You can use this approach to map it to `List<String>`:

```
List<String> productNames = productList.parallelStream()
                              .map(Product::getPName)
                              .collect(toList());
```

**Edit:**

- [Is it possible to use Java 8 for Android development?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23318109/is-it-possible-to-use-java-8-for-android-development)

Comment: u could have commented @mzy

Answer (score 0):

This way might be helpful:

```
class Product {
    int pId;
    String pName;
    int pPrice;
}

List<Product> products = new ArrayList<>();

// add products

List<String> names = new AbstractList<String>() {
    @Override
    public String get(int location) {
        return products.get(location).pName;
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return products.size();
    }
}
```