# Android: unsupported class file version 52.0

Tags: java, android, android-studio, java-8

I am developing android and using `jdk 1.8.0_74`. The android project uses also `Java version 1.8`. The `JAVA_HOME` is also set to the `jdk 1.8`. I download the newest packages in the `sdk manager`, cleaned the project, invalidated caches, restarted the android studio ...

I cloned an existing project from a repository and get the following unsupported class file error.

```
PARSE ERROR: 
unsupported class file version 52.0
...while parsing android/support/design/R.class
...
```

The whole project is working on another computer with the same java version.

Please can anyone help me?

Comment: @MorrisonChang - I read the article but this is only a discussion about if it is possible but it should be possible because the project is running on other computers

Comment: yes it is possible to run java 8 now, https://developer.android.com/preview/j8-jack.html you need android studio 2.1 to do it though

Comment: If you want to run Java 8 on Android see http://stackoverflow.com/a/35907821/295004 - do realize it is very, very new.

Comment: I tried all of this but it is still not working always the same error.