# LibGDX and Java 8 source compatibilty

Tags: java, android, eclipse, libgdx, java-8

I have a libGDX(1.9.2) project with a Core project with Java 7 compliance settings and an Android project with Java 6 compliance settings in Eclipse projects.

That works great, BUT if I change the compliance settings of the Core project to Java 8, the Android build fails with the following exception:

```
Caused by: com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: bad class file magic (cafebabe) or version (0034.0000)
```

I tried to modify the build.gradle of the Core and the Android project but nothing fixed the problem so far.

I understand that the Android requires Java 6, but if the Core project built with Java 7 there is no problem.

Is libGDX compatible with Java 8 and if it is then how can I make it work?

Comment: Is your Android engine Java 8 compatible?

Comment: I can't check it now, but I downloaded it a few weeks ago, updated and I use Android 6.0 for testing on not virtual phone. AFAIK remember it's called android 23.

Comment: Eclipse doesn't let me set 1.8 compliance for that project.

Comment: Sounds like you are stuck on Java 7 with this project.

Comment: Am afraid too, but I wanted to ask it, maybe somebody who is related to the libgdx development knows (or will know later) the answer. Thanks anyway!

Comment: It is not related to libgdx, android doesn't support java 8. Check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23318109/is-it-possible-to-use-java-8-for-android-development

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With android N release you can enable jack & jill to use [java 8 features](http://developer.android.com/preview/j8-jack.html), but if you don't want to use jack & jill, you can use [retrolambda](https://github.com/orfjackal/retrolambda) to have lambda expressions, method references and try-with-resources statements.

Both of these ways allow you to set your source compatibility to java 1.8, so you can build your project without any problem.

Comment: If I use this new N version, that would mean I cannot run my application on my 6.0 phone right?

Comment: @gaRos no, just update your sdk to the newest version and use java 8 features in both N and pre-N