# Saving Game Scores

Tags: java, save, load, bufferedreader, bufferedwriter

i am trying to make a highscore for a hangman game. So i need to save it so it doesnt restart everytime u start the game or return to the menu.. so I have a playstate that records the wins and losses at the end of the game and if the user leaves before solving it adds a loss. I found a tutorial to save via a SavaData file.. the problem is it saves an empty file nothing in there but has 2 empty lines.. and so i get a numberformatexception null.. i had it working before but it still would not read the line and would return an error numberformatexception Integer.parseInt.. I know the problem is in reading lines and now i dont know what went wrong please help me .. whats wrong with the code?? thanx

this is the saving code...

```
 private void createSaveData() {

        File file = new File(saveDataPath, filename);
        try {

            FileWriter output = new FileWriter(file);
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(output);
            writer.write("" + 0);
            writer.newLine();
            writer.write("" + 0);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private void setScores() {

        FileWriter output = null;

        try {

            File F = new File(saveDataPath, filename);
            output = new FileWriter(F);
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(output);
            writer.write(wins);
            writer.newLine();
            writer.write(losses);
            writer.close();

        }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void loadScores() {
    try {

        File F = new File(saveDataPath, filename);

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(F)));

        String line = reader.readLine();

        line = reader.readLine();
        wins = Integer.parseInt(line);

        line = reader.readLine();
        losses = Integer.parseInt(line);

        reader.close();


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

i then add loadScore(); at the begging of the playstate.. and setScore(); after a win++ or a loss++..

i have another highscorestate that calls on playstate and gets the wins and lossess as an integer and that works no problems cause it draws 0  ,   0 .

in my render method i have this if the tries are too much or if the correct answer is guessed...

```
    if (tries == 6) {

        currentWord = ranWord;
        execcurrentframe.setRegion(eman.ExecLoss.getKeyFrame(elapsedTime, false));
        hangcurrentframe.setRegion(hman.hangdead.getKeyFrame(elapsedTime, false));
        Wordsfont.draw(batch, "Game Over", eman.getPosition().x + 60, hman.getPosition().y + 70);
        batch.draw(fu, 160, 510);

        if (leverpressed == false){

            bksound.stop();
            lever.play();
            leverpressed = true;

        }

        if (lossrecorded == false) {
            losses += 1;
            System.out.print("Losses = " + losses);
            setScores();
            lossrecorded = true;

        }
    }
    else if (CorrectAnswer == true) {
        hangcurrentframe.setRegion(hman.hangwin.getKeyFrame(elapsedTime, false));
        Wordsfont.draw(batch, "You Won", eman.getPosition().x + 60, hman.getPosition().y + 70);


        if (winrecorded == false) {
            bksound.stop();
            victory.play();
            wins += 1;
            System.out.print("Wins = " + wins);
            setScores();
            winrecorded = true;

        }
    }
```

Comment: One comment, be sure to close the writer in `createSaveData()`. You should also put all of the `.close()` method calls in a finally block, or use the Java 7 try-with-resources approach.

Comment: i noticed that too even though in the tutorial he didnt add.. still doesnt help only changed the error too .lang.NumberFormatException: For input string:""  +  plus the reading problem.. java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:481)

Comment: (1) Are you using both `createSaveData` and `setScores`? What is the type of `wins` and `losses`?

Comment: i added the wins loss to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest the following changes.

1. Use a single `writeSaveData` method. The code between `createSaveData` and `setScores` is largely duplicated. Also, use the `Integer.toString()` to write the output. Also, ensure the stream is closed (here using try with resources).

   ```
   private void writeSaveData(int wins, int losses)
   {
     File file = new File(saveDataPath, filename);
     try (BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file))) {
       writer.write(Integer.toString(wins));
       writer.newLine();
       writer.write(Integer.toString(losses));

     }
     catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }

   }
   ```
2. There is an extra `readLine()` in the `loadScores()` method. Remove that extra line. Change to use try with resources.

   ```
   private void loadScores()
   {
     File file = new File(saveDataPath, filename);

     try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file)))) {
       String line = reader.readLine();

       // line = reader.readLine() <-- REMOVE THIS LINE
       wins = Integer.parseInt(line);

       line = reader.readLine();
       losses = Integer.parseInt(line);

       reader.close();


     }
     catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
     }
   }
   ```

**EDIT**: If one cannot use try with resources, then the following approach may be used instead.

```
private void loadScores()
{
    File file = new File(saveDataPath, filename);

    BufferedReader reader = null;
    //        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file)))) {
    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file)));            
        String line = reader.readLine();

        wins = Integer.parseInt(line);

        line = reader.readLine();
        losses = Integer.parseInt(line);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        if (reader != null) {
            try {
                reader.close();
            }
            catch (IOException ioe) {
                ioe.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

A similar modification may be made to the suggested `writeSaveData()` or other methods.

Comment: getting an error saying Try with resources is not supported at this language level?? is that a version issue or just the wrong imported library?  ty for you help

Comment: i changed the vs. to 1.7 but still gettting an error.. any idea y?? using android studios

Comment: I am not sure how you are compiling (i.e., IDE, javac, etc). If the try with resources is not available, you can move the declarations outside of the try, and then add a finally { } to close them. I will try to update the answer in a moment.

Comment: WRT to the Java, version and android studio, [this link may help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23318109/is-it-possible-to-use-java-8-for-android-development)

Comment: Hey Kevin.. I dont understand what u did.. or most of the code but I LOVE U man it works.. thats it IM done with my first game..

Answer (score 0):

You have overlooked one important part of the original `createSaveData` method:

```
writer.write("" + 0);
```

See that `"" + 0`? It effectively converts the integer to a string (though there are more elegant ways of doing this).

`BufferedWriter` has overloaded `write` method. This means there is a different method that is called when the parameter is a `String`, and a different one when the parameter is an `int`.

You have called the version whose parameter is an `int`. Its [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#write%28int%29) says:

> `public void write(int c) throws IOException`
>
> Writes a single character.
>
> **Overrides**:
>
> write in class Writer
>
> **Parameters:**
>
> `c` - `int` specifying a character to be
>   written
>
> **Throws:**
>
> `IOException` - If an I/O error occurs

This tells you that it considers the `int` that you passed as a character. That is, if you give it the int `65`, it will be taken as the character `A`. If you give it the int `48`, it will be taken as the character `0`.

If you give it the integer `0`, this is the `NUL` control character.

When you read that back as a string, it is taken as a single-character string containing the `NUL` character. Of course, that's not a valid string format for a number.

So replace

```
        writer.write(wins);
```

With

```
        writer.write(String.valueOf(wins));
```

And do the same for losses.

Comment: thank you for the info ... im new to this but i understand what ur saying i turned the integer to a string and then called on it as an int.. gonna try the below method since it combines my two methods.. if not will do this one