# Android Studio compile project with Java 8?

Tags: android-studio, java-8

I'm trying to compile a project using java 8.

I've set the correct jdk as shown in the image:

[image: JDK location]

Also changed the target version:

[image: Target version]

But I still got the error:
**compileSdkVersion 'android-24' requires JDK 1.8 or later to compile.**

Where am I wrong?

EDIT: I'm on Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: The path to your jdk should be more specific. In Mac I have `jdk1.8.0_92.jdk/Contents/Home`

Comment: @JuanCruzSoler my path is correct, because I'm running Ubuntu

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to use Java 8 for Android development?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23318109/is-it-possible-to-use-java-8-for-android-development)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When goes to JDK setting you can:

add in "*android app*" module **build.gradle**

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

setup sdk path in **gradle.properties**

```
org.gradle.java.home=/path_to_java_sdk_8/jdk1.8
```

check also **.idea/modules/compiler.xml** against 1.7/1.8

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project version="4">
  <component name="CompilerConfiguration">
      ...
    <bytecodeTargetLevel target="1.8">
      <module name="app" target="1.7" />
    </bytecodeTargetLevel>
  </component>
```

and **misc.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <project version="4">
    ....
   <component name="ProjectRootManager" version="2" languageLevel="JDK_1_7" 
              default="false" assert-keyword="true" 
              jdk-15="true" project-jdk-name="1.8" project-jdk-type="JavaSDK">
     <output url="file://$PROJECT_DIR$/build/classes" />
  </component>
  <component name="ProjectType">
    <option name="id" value="Android" />
  </component>
 </project>
```

BTW: if you want compile againsta java 1.8 you need to uae "jack"
see https://source.android.com/source/jack.html

Comment: Setting org.gradle.java.home=/path_to_java_sdk_8/jdk1.8 did the trick! Thanks!

Comment: @Eric - I'm glad that I helped - it would be nice if you could vote up also :)

Answer (score 3):

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion = '28.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "your package name"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}
```