# How to use Realm database with Java 8 features

Tags: java, android, gradle, java-8, realm

I am new to using Realm database for Android.

I modified my gradle files to include the [Jack toolchain](https://developer.android.com/preview/j8-jack.html) so that I could use Java 8 language features. I also modified the gradle files to install the [Realm plugin](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/). When I synced the project gradle files, I received the following error: `Error:Could not find property 'options' on task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJack'`. The two modifications work fine on their own, but for some reason I cannot have both at the same time.

I would very much appreciate help on this matter.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23318109/is-it-possible-to-use-java-8-for-android-development check this answer?

Answer (score 7):

It is not possible to use Jack compiler with Realm at the moment, because Jack does not support bytecode manipulation (Javassist / Transform API).

In order to use lambdas, it's easier for you to use Retrolambda instead for the time being.

```
buildscript {
     //...
     dependencies {
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:1.1.0"
        classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.2.5'
    }
}
```

And

```
apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'

android {
    ...

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
```

Comment: Aw, that's a shame. Thanks for your response regardless.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately Jack compiler and Realm can't play together right now. Please follow [that topic](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/3038). [That one](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=210730&q=Jack%20transform&colspec=ID%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars%20Reporter%20Opened) is also useful.

Comment: Thanks for providing me with those links.