# android studio - inner class errors

Tags: java, android-studio

I'm getting these errors when I build my project. It successfully builds but I'm not entirely sure why I'm getting them. How do I get rid of them? Thank you

```
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(com.instabug.library.c) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
```

I looked around for a couple of hours and did as some guys suggested of adding different things to my proguard-rules.pro file such as

```
-keepattributes InnerClasses
-dontoptimize
-dontwarn InnerClasses
-keepattributes EnclosingMethod
```

I've tried these in different orders and nothing.

Comment: Please show the code which causes the errors.

Comment: What version of the JDK do you have installed?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Thanks for the quick answer. How do I find it? It's a huge project and double clicking the errors doesn't take me to any specific code. Edit: JDK 1.8.0_111

Comment: > Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class (com.instabug.library.c)

Comment: see this question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23318109/is-it-possible-to-use-java-8-for-android-development)

Comment: @RaminPakzood Reverting to jdk 7 gives me the same errors. This is frustrating! Thanks for your help