# What is the best way to avoid java compatibility issues with android studio?

Tags: java, android-studio, build.gradle, backwards-compatibility

I am currently creating a project on android studio and i have been having some gradle errors due to compatibility issues. i do have a java class in which some functions are just specific to java 8. 
The gradle error is long and I was unable to narrow it down to the problematic function.

**Q1:My entire project runs on java 7 is there any ways to avoid compatibility issues with AS without switching to java 8?

Q2:Can writing the java codes in an editor like eclipse (or any other you know of) help me reduce compatibility issues?**

Thanks

L

Comment: try to read this maybe it will enlighten your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23318109/is-it-possible-to-use-java-8-for-android-development

Comment: You cannot use methods and features introduced in java 8 in any older java version. You must either use alrernative methods which is available in java 7 or witch to java 8