# Android Studio Module/Dependency JDBC Issues

Tags: android, jdbc

I am trying to setup a JDBC jar for my android studio project.  I am currently getting an error when trying to launch the application due to the Module/Dependency I added.

Stack Trace

```
Error:Gradle: Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: Dex cannot parse version 52 byte code.
This is caused by library dependencies that have been compiled using Java 8 or above.
If you are using the 'java' gradle plugin in a library submodule add 
targetCompatibility = '1.7'
sourceCompatibility = '1.7'
to that submodule's build.gradle file.
```

I tried following the steps in the trace and modifying the build.gradle file but could not resolve the issue. I am not sure if I need to uninstall and reinstall the module and set the compiler to 1.7 in the process or if I can even do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get it to work you'll need a Java 7 compiled jar. See: [Is it possible to use Java 8 for Android development?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23318109/is-it-possible-to-use-java-8-for-android-development).

Additionally not sure why you are trying to include a JDBC driver into Android app, but recommend reading this: [JDBC vs Web Service for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15853367/jdbc-vs-web-service-for-android)