# Android Jetty fatal exception

Tags: java, android, jetty

I am working on an Android web server with Jetty. There are two files: MainActivity.java and Servlet.java which contains my main server class ExampleServlet. Files are shown below:

**Servlet.java**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpStatus;

class ExampleServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        resp.setStatus(HttpStatus.OK_200);
        resp.getWriter().println("Hello World");
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.joey.myproject;

import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler;
import com.example.joey.myproject.ExampleServlet;
import javax.servlet.Servlet;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Server server = new Server(7070);
        ServletContextHandler handler = new ServletContextHandler(server, "/example");
        handler.addServlet(ExampleServlet.class, "/");
        try {
            server.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

When I install APK and run, the app is crashing. And I am getting this error on logcat:

```
08-28 10:07:02.869 29531-29531/com.example.joey.myproject E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConfiguration.<init>(HttpConfiguration.java:61)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnectionFactory.<init>(HttpConnectionFactory.java:40)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.<init>(ServerConnector.java:96)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.<init>(Server.java:113)
        at com.example.joey.myproject.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:125)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5247)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1082)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2162)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2225)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:151)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1301)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5071)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.BufferUtil.toBuffer(BufferUtil.java:850)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpScheme.<init>(HttpScheme.java:52)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpScheme.<clinit>(HttpScheme.java:32)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConfiguration.<init>(HttpConfiguration.java:61) 
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnectionFactory.<init>(HttpConnectionFactory.java:40) 
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.<init>(ServerConnector.java:96) 
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.<init>(Server.java:113) 
        at com.example.joey.myproject.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:125) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5247) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1082) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2162) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2225) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:151) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1301) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5071) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557) 
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are running your code in a jvm lower than 7 which does not contain the Java nio package.

So you have to upgrade your jvm to Java 1.7 or higher

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/StandardCharsets.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My Java version is 8 update 171. Build number 1.8.0_171-b11. Is it what you mentioned?

Comment: @eternal_peace you are sure that this is the Version you use at runtime?

Comment: I get this information from "About Java" program which installed on my computer. Can it differs with runtime? Or how can I get runtime version?

Comment: On my Android 4.1.2 phone

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/26476839/3636601. Looks like android uses java6 in this version

Comment: My gradle file has `compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }` as solution says

Comment: But compiling and running are two different things @eternal_peace