# How to call Kotlin function with function as parameter in Java Code?

Tags: java, android, lambda, kotlin

I have a kotlin method as follows:

```
fun methodWithCallBackAsParameter(callback:() -> Unit) {
    //Do Somejob
    callback()
}
```

In kotlin we simply use this method with following syntax:

```
methodWithCallBackAsParameter {
    //Some Instructions here.
}
```

Now I want to use this Kotlin method in a Java class but I am not able to figure out how.

Comment: Doesn't `methodWithCallbackAsParameter(() -> { });` work?

Comment: It says missing return statement.

Comment: I tried returning Unit.INSTANCE; it now says,     Lambda expressions are not supported at language level 7.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to use Java 8 for Android development?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23318109/is-it-possible-to-use-java-8-for-android-development)

Comment: If you are using Android Studio 3.0+ then you just need to enable Java 8 language features by copy-pasting a block of code into your build.gradle, see https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support

Answer (score 5):

Just return Unit.INSTANCE in the end of the lambda expression.

Comment: I tried returning Unit.INSTANCE; it now says, Lambda expressions are not supported at language level 7.

Comment: Either set language level to 1.8 or transform the lambda into anonymous class.
This error occurred because lambdas are supported from Java 1.8, and your project uses Java 1.7.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to use lambda in android you have to change your app to use Java 1.8 instead of 1.7 use can do that by it from gradle

```
android {
  ...
  // Configure only for each module that uses Java 8
  // language features (either in its source code or
  // through dependencies).
  compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
  }
}
```

for more look this documentation https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to do this.

```kotlin
    public class Program {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FunctionKt.methodWithCallBackAsParameter(() -> {
            System.out.printf("do something");
            return null;
        });
    }
}
```

In this example, the function `methodWithCallBackAsParameter` was defined in the `function.kt` file.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

Supposing the kotlin method is

```
fun handleResult(
    data: Intent?,
    callbackSuccess: (String) -> Unit,
    callbackError: (String) -> Unit
)
```

Then when you call this from Java you call it like this (either by matching the signature or doing some logic inside)

```
    handleResult(data, this::success, this::failure);

    handleResult(data, (statusCode) -> success(statusCode), (errorMessage) -> failure(errorMessage));


    private Unit failure(String errorMessage) {
        // do something java here
        return Unit.INSTANCE;
    }

    private Unit success(String code) {
        // do something java here
        return Unit.INSTANCE;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

When use in Java: `callback: () -> Unit = new Function0<>()`