# Android studio: How make system jdk work to use JAVA_HOME?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a problem with my android studio project jdk location

- my system jdk path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.1
- android project: D:\Android Studio\jre

When I change JDK location from jre to system path, building android errors
Gradle sync failed: Cause: invalid type code: xx

But I want to use system jdk instead of Android Studio\jre to use JAVA_HOME

How can I do?
My andoid studio:

- Android Gradle Plugin Version: 4.0.0
- Gradle Version: 6.1.1

Thanks

Comment: Please have a look on the below two links:
1. https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support    
2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23318109/is-it-possible-to-use-java-8-for-android-development