# Android Studio, Java 8, and Function

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I installed the latest Java 8 on my Mac and the latest Android Studio. In Android Studio I cannot find java.util.function. This leads me to believe that it's not using Java 8.  I have search for a log time and the only Java I have on my Mac is Java 8.  I also checked the Project Structure and it's pointing to Java 8. I reinstalled Android Studio, created a new project, and I still cannot import java.util.function.  Does Android studio really work with Java 8?  Any suggestions on how to get access to java.util.function?

Comment: Thanks to everyone who answered.  It was not clear to me. I'm new to Android with lots of iOS experience. I was trying to create the equivalent of an iOS Swift closure.  After much reading it seemed like Java 8 Lambda/Function would be perfect. I guess I'll have to figure this our for Java 6 or 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In Android Studio I cannot find `java.util.function`

Android does not yet support Java 8, so this is no surprise. As of KitKat, Android targets Java 1.7.

> This leads me to believe that it's not using Java 8

You are right.

> Any suggestions on how to get access to `java.util.function`?

This is not really possible. If it was pure Java code you could have a chance of retrofitting the code in an Android compatible way. But `java.util.function` (and `@FunctionalInterface`) is part of the language spec so it doesn't really make sense to even try.

**Related discussions:**

- [Does Android have any plans for Java 8?](http://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/22mh0r/does_android_have_any_plans_for_java_8/)  (Reddit /r/androiddev)
- [Which JDK version (Language Level) is required for Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17869069/which-jdk-version-language-level-is-required-for-android-studio)
- [How does Android's Java version relate to a Java SE version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7535385/how-does-androids-java-version-relate-to-a-java-se-version)
- [Is it possible to use Java 8 for Android development?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23318109/is-it-possible-to-use-java-8-for-android-development)

Answer (score 2):

> Does Android studio really work with Java 8?

Android doesn't support Java 8. Some of the Java 1.7 features are supported since kitkat