# In Android, which Java version should I compile the code for, and how to set it for Ant?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, ant

When building an Android application, which Java version should I compile the code for? I'd guess this depends on the `minSdkVersion`? And if so, where can I find the required Java version for each `minSdkVersion`?

And once I determine the Java version I want, how do I set it? I build my project using Ant (from the command line). Currently it seems to always use 1.5 because the `build.xml` file imports `${sdk.dir}/tools/ant/build.xml` which contains:

```
<property name="java.target" value="1.5" />
<property name="java.source" value="1.5" />
...

<javac ... source="${java.source}" target="${java.target}" ... >
```

Should I change it there? Is there a way to set it per project?

And is there a way to set the Java version if I build using Eclipse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Eclipse, just right-click on the project, then Properties|Java Compiler. Then choose the desired java compliance level.

Look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7535385/274340) about the relation between the Android SDK and the Java runtime version.
As reported there:

> With Android KitKat (buildToolsVersion 19 you can use 1.7
>   [tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/)

Comment: Thanx. Is there a way to see which target Java version is used to build the project in Eclipse, to make sure that it does indeed compile to the version I want?

Comment: I looked at your link and I still can't find an answer to the question: if I develop for Android API level `X`, which Java version should I use? I see that version 6 was supported, and at some point version 7 was supported too. Since which Android API level is Java 7 supported? And where can I find current information about the connection between Android API level and the Java version?

Comment: With Android KitKat (buildToolsVersion 19 you can use 1.7 http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Using-sourceCompatibility-1.7

Comment: Thanx! Perhaps u can add your comment to your answer, and then I can formally "accept" it.

Comment: @YaronCohen-Tal I added the comment. Regards

Answer (score 0):

Seems like I found an answer at least to one of my questions: to change the Java version for Ant (when used from the command line) I created a file "ant.properties" at the top level directory of my project with the contents:

```
java.target=1.7
java.source=1.7
```

(to change to Java 7). I don't know, though, if it also affects building inside Eclipse.