# Android - Which Java version(s) is used in my app?

Tags: java, android

I understand Android is build using the Java programming language. With different types of Java versions come different features/fixes/bugs etc. I am developing with a minimum SDK of 4.4. The thing I still don't understand is when I package this app which version of Java will run it? Does my app use the java version which I used to develop to run my app on all devices, does each sdk use it's own Java version, or something completely different?

Comment: There's no Java code running on an Android device, so are you talking about what version of Java your code is compiled with?

Comment: @ianhanniballake I guess so then? For example the Java class HttpURLConnection had some improvements done from Java 6 to 7. One fix is very important to me which only works in Java 7. This is why I want to make sure when I develop for devices running on older SDK's that the HttpURLConnection from Java 7 is used.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does Android's Java version relate to a Java SE version?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7535385/how-does-androids-java-version-relate-to-a-java-se-version)

Answer (score 0):

Related: [How does Android's Java version relate to a Java SE version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7535385/how-does-androids-java-version-relate-to-a-java-se-version)

Short answer is that Android uses its own version of Java, which doesn't exactly correspond to the current Java version. For example, Android currently [supports](https://developer.android.com/guide/platform/j8-jack.html) all of Java 7's features, but only a subset of Java 8 features.

Furthermore, Android does *not* use the Java Virtual Machine. It used the Dalvik virtual machine until 4.4, and current versions use Android Runtime.